# Trouble is adding multi Edit Text Views

Tags: android, scrollview, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I am trying to add five Edit Text Views on the click of a button in a Scroll View. But when i am clicking the button, the Edit Text View appearing is not in the Scroll View but in the Main Linear Layout.
 What to do, for Edit Text View to get appear in Scroll View.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_editmessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_editMessage" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="@string/et_messageToSend" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ScrView"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/et_display" >
        </EditText>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bpickperson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b_pick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/balert"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b_alert" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/baddmorecontacts"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b_addmorecontacts" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_facebook"
            android:layout_width="144dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b_facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_twitter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b_twitter" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
        String separator = "; ";
        private Button btn_cntct;
        public int REQUESTCODE = 1;
        private LinearLayout layoutLinear;
        private Button btn_addmore_cntct;
        int temp;
        ScrollView ScrView;
        Context c = MainActivity.this;
        Button b_alert;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // defining button elements for picking contacts from phone-book
            btn_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpickperson);
            btn_cntct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // using Intent for fetching contacts from phone-book
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
                }

            });

            // defining button and edit-text values for adding mutli edit-texts
            // views
                temp = 1;
            layoutLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
            ScrView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrView);
            btn_addmore_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddmorecontacts);
            btn_addmore_cntct.setOnClickListener(OnClick());
            EditText editview = new EditText(this);
            editview.setText("Add more");

        }

        // implementing OnClickListener OnClick() method for "btn_addmore_cntct"
        // button
        private OnClickListener OnClick() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // changing return type "null" to "new OnClickListner"
            return new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (temp <= 2) {
                    EditText tab = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                    tab.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tab.setEnabled(false);
                    tab.setFocusable(false);
//                  layoutLinear.addView(tab,0);
                    ScrView.addView(tab,0);
                    temp++;
                } else {
                    // Print message to user Cant add more editText.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No More Contacts",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.i("data", uri.toString());
                if (uri != null) {
                    Cursor c = null;
                    try {
                        c = getContentResolver()
                                .query(uri,
                                        new String[] {
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                        null, null, null);

                        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                            String name = c.getString(0);
                            String number = c.getString(1);
                            int type = c.getInt(2);

                            showSelectedNumber(name, number, type);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            c.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // defining showSelectedNummber to display selected contact from phone-book
        // to Edit-Text View
        String selectedNum = " ";

        public void showSelectedNumber(String name, String number, int type) {
            if (layoutLinear == null) {
                Log.i("layoutLinear is null", "null");
            } else {
                Log.i("layoutLinear is not  null", "not null");

            }

            EditText userNumber = (EditText) layoutLinear.getChildAt(0);
            if (userNumber == null) {
                Log.i("edittext is null", "null");
            } else {
                Log.i("edittext is not  null", "not null");

            }
            String typeNumber = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                    .getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, "");
            // preventing number duplicacy and raising toast
            if (selectedNum.contains(number)) {
                // do nothing
                // alert user that number is already selected
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Selected Contact Already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else
                userNumber.setText(name + ":" + number + " " + typeNumber);
            selectedNum = selectedNum + number;

        }
    }
```

LogCat

```
02-07 11:44:46.116: D/AndroidRuntime(1281): Shutting down VM
02-07 11:44:46.116: W/dalvikvm(1281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:220)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at com.example.zzz1.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:157)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-07 11:44:46.126: E/AndroidRuntime(1281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You can initially add all edittext(5) in scrollview and make invisible to them..& on button click make it visible

Comment: @yuva yeah but i want to do it this way. Can u possibly suggest where i am doing wrong

Comment: @yuva  this is my initial code. I tried it in scroll View also but application was force closing

Comment: where you were getting force close??put your logcat here,Try by making height fill parent of scroll view

Comment: i have posted my locgcat , and have edited the the question also. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add edittext in scrollview ScrView.addView(tab)

Comment: Application stopped unexpectedly

Comment: You have to insert Linearlayout inside scrollview and then add edit text in linearlayout.scroll view allows only one direct child so

Comment: means I have to add another linear layout in the Scroll View, in which Edit Text Views Will gets appear ??

Comment: yeah.<ScrollView><LinearLayout><EditText>...<EditText></LinearLayout></ScrollView>

Comment: as i am new to android, can you please tell me how should i set the height and width of the linear layout in order to overlap the Scroll View

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46988/discussion-between-bhanu-kaushik-and-yuva)

Comment: yeah, thanks man, the <ScrollView><LinearLayout><EditText>...<EditText></LinearLayout></ScrollVie‌​w> method worked. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView must have a child layout to add any view to it.

Add your textview to the linear layout
Add a LinearLayout to Scrollview.
Add scrollview to your parent layout

This is the xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the activity java class

```
    LinearLayout l,scl;
    Button b1;
EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5;
ScrollView sv;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainl);
    scl=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scLay);
    sv=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    e1=new EditText(this);  
    e2=new EditText(this);  
    e3=new EditText(this);  
    e4=new EditText(this);  
    e5=new EditText(this);  
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scl.addView(e1);
            scl.addView(e2);
            scl.addView(e3);
            scl.addView(e4);
            scl.addView(e5);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i have added a new Linear Layout in the Scroll View keeping Edit Text in the Linear Layout.  Will it work ?